# test for named character(0) vector in R

Tags: r

I have a function which returns the following vector in R

```
vec
#named character(0)
```

Since it is a named vector, I am not able to test the following on it

is.na()

```
is.na(vec)
# named logical(0)
```

is.null

```
is.null(vec)
# [1] FALSE
```

identical(vec,character(0)

```
identical(vec,character(0)
# [1] FALSE
```

How do I write a test on it to check if it is a named character(0) vector and then assign it to a NULL value?

Comment: `is.character(x) && length(x) == 0 && !is.null(attr(x, "name"))`

Comment: However, do you _really_ want to check for _all_ of that? Sounds like checking `length(x) == 0` might suffice?

Comment: I think checking `length(x)==0` should suffice, cause in my case I already know its a character vector. Thanks

Comment: how did you make a _named_ length 0 vector

Comment: @rawr maybe through subsetting: `str(c(a=1)[FALSE])`

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked by checking whether the length of the named character is equal to zero:

```
if (length(vec) == 0) {
    vec <- NA
}
```